# Вставка точки в полигон

Tags: c++, алгоритм, qt, геометрия

Есть некоторая ломаная кривая, заданная в виде набора точек. Пытаюсь придумать алгоритм вставки новой точки в эту кривую. Никак не могу придумать как мне определить позицию вставки.

Первая мысль была рассматривать треугольники, которые образует новая точка и пара существующих соседних точек, и выбирать треугольник с наименьшим периметром. Однако для такого случая
[image]
алгоритм сочтет нужным вставить новую точку между первой и второй. Хотя вторая и третья явно подходят лучше.

Так же думал рассматривать те же треугольники, и выбирать с наименьшей высотой. Но и тут алгоритм в определенных ситуациях будет работать неправильно. Например тут [image]

алгоритм выберет позицию между точками 3 и 4, вмето 1 и 2.

Чтобы исключить такие случаи, решил рассматривать только треугольники с острыми углами у основания. Но и тут нашлись исключения.
[image]
Оба треугольника-кандидата имеют тупые углы у основания.

Вообщем я в тупике. Наверняка у этой проблемы есть какое-то решение, ну или хотя бы название которое можно загуглить. Ведь пишут же люди всякие автокады и тому подобное.

Comment: Ну, вообще-то это не кривая, но фиг с ним :) Вы не могли бы как-то сформулировать критерий вставки? Просто что-то не очень понятно, чего именно вы хотите добиться. Новая точка задана, и вам нужно указать, между какими точками она должна быть? или вы вычисляете координаты новой точки?

Comment: Я бы рассмотрел условие минимального изменения длины ломаной после вставки точки как основное.

Comment: В дополнение к уважаемому Harry, хотелось бы услышать формулировку исходной задачи - непонятно, что Вы хотите

Comment: @Harry, если б я сам знал этот критерий :) Я делаю графический редактор.  Нужна возможность добавить в ломаною новую вершину, когда пользователь кликает мышью в некоторую окрестность. Выходит что точка у меня есть, и мне нужно определиться куда её вставить.

Comment: @Igor. Думаю это дало бы нужный результат, но сложность получится O(n^2). Хотелось бы управиться за O(n) :)

Comment: т.е. сравнивал бы сумму длин двух новых отрезков по отношению к длине старого отрезка, который исчезнет

Comment: я не совсем понимаю, как получается n в квадрате

Comment: Вообще-то O(n) - для каждого звена. Есть еще вариант - минимальная площадь треугольника, образованного точкой и звеном. Нет, плохо - см. первый рисунок...

Comment: "... когда пользователь кликает мышью в некоторую окрестность..." в этой ситуации, ИМХО, не нужно решать за пользователя, а нужно предоставить выбор пользователю.

Comment: @Igor, понял, туплю) Я хотел пересчитывать длину всей кривой)

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов, мой начальник никогда такое не одобрит) Пользователя лучше лишний раз не тревожить

Comment: А здесь не нужно напрягать пользователя - пользователь ставит мышом точку на ломанную и тянет туда, куда ему нужно.

Comment: @Igor, я никак не могу придумать случай, когда ваш вариант работал бы неправильно. Оформите в виде ответа, я его приму.

Comment: Задача сформулирована бессмысленно, а точнее не сформулирована вообще. Не существует никакого однозначного или "естественного" способа вставки точки в ломаную. Поэтому пока не сформулирован четкий критерии оптимизации иля хотя бы более-менее осмысленные пожелания по поводу результата, говорить не о чем.

Comment: присоеднияюсь к тому, что не ясны требования. Но судя по тому что вы хотите сделать, могу предложить найти такие две точки на ломаной расстояние до которых максимально и вставить между ними эту точку (например по середнине) ??

Comment: "Первая мысль была рассматривать треугольники, которые образует новая точка и пара существующих соседних точек [...] алгоритм сочтет нужным вставить новую точку между первой и второй" - что за белиберда? Какой "алгоритм"? И почему он именно сочтет нужным вставить новую точку между первой и второй?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я бы рассмотрел условие минимального изменения длины ломаной после вставки точки как основное.

Только надо решить, смотреть ли на абсолютное увеличение длины, или по отношению к тому сегменту, который заменяется на два.

Comment: Я рассчитывал *старый - (новый + новый)*. Наилучший вариант всегда давал минимальное значение. Во всяком случае я не смог придумать, ситуацию, когда такой алгоритм будет работать неправильно

Comment: Еще одна возможная метрика - изменение суммы углов - стремиться к наименьшему. Также, возможно, стоит блокировать самопересечения.